# Add html to perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl

Am trying to replace all `` with a HTML code tag

replace:

```
$string = "Foo `FooBar` Bar";
```

with:

```
$string = "Foo <code>FooBar</code> Bar";
```

i tried these

```
$pattern = '`(.*?)`';

my $replace = "<code/>$&</code>";
$subject =~ s/$pattern/$replace/im;

#And

$subject =~ s/$pattern/<code/>$&</code>/im;
```

but none of them works.

Comment: Mind the slashes.

Comment: Your string is in `$string` but you're doing the `s///` on `$subject`. Could you show your actual code? And could you show what doesn't work?

Comment: Is that Markdown? If so, take a look at [Text::Markdown](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Markdown).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you meant `$string` instead of `$subject`...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $string = "Foo `FooBar` Bar";

my $pattern = '`(.*?)`';
my $replace = "<code/>$&</code>";

$string =~ s{$pattern}{$replace}im;
say $string;
```

This results in...

```
$ perl ~/tmp/test.plx
Use of uninitialized value $& in concatenation (.) or string at /Users/schwern/tmp/test.plx line 9.
Foo <code/></code> Bar
```

There's some problems here. First, `$&` means the string matched by the last match. That would be all of `` `FooBar` ``. You just want `FooBar` which is inside capturing parens. You get that with `$1`. See [Extracting Matches in the Perl Regex Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches).

Second is `$&` and `$1` are variables. If you put them in double quotes like `$replace = "<code/>$&</code>"` then Perl will *immediately* interpolate them. That means `$replace` is `<code/></code>`. This is where the warning comes from. If you want to use `$1` it has to go directly into the replace.

Finally, when quoting regexes it's best to use `qr{}`. That does special regex quoting. It avoids all sorts of quoting issues.

Put it all together...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $string = "Foo `FooBar` Bar";

my $pattern = qr{`(.*?)`};
$string =~ s{$pattern}{<code/>$1</code>}im;

say $string;
```

Comment: is there any other way to use `$1` without putting it directly to replace. like making something like `$replace = '<code>$i</code>'`

Comment: @ChrysUgwu Yes, ***but I don't recommend it*** because it's a security hole. If you use `s{}{}e` the right hand side will be eval'd as if it were code. But now you're vulnerable to code injection. It works like interpolation. `my $foo = 23; my $bar = q[this $foo]; print "$bar"` will say `this $foo`. But if you `print eval qq["$bar"]` you get `this 23`... but `$bar` could contain any code.

Comment: so Perl dosnt provide any secured pattern replacement like php? http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: @ChrysUgwu Search and replace is secure, unless you make it insecure. But it doesn't support expanding `$1` in strings like PHP does in Example #1. There might be away to do it, but I don't know it. I'd suggest asking that as a new question.